# Selecting Correct Statistical Methodology

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, svm, cart

I am designing a predictive model, and I am unsure of how to group the data from individuals companies, or whether I even need to group that data, and it's valid to treat each row as an independent event.

The data will roughly be as given below. The values given are about what will be expected. 80 companies are surveyed. Trait_1 to Trait_4 are integers, will have a minimum value of zero, a mean of 2, and a standard deviation of 1.5, and the max observed value is 6. The trait can be accurately measured, and is not subjective. It is assumed that when Trait_1 to Trait_4 are higher, Project success will be more likely. It is expected that different Traits will be more important than others.  There will be a different number of qualifying projects data from each company (from 2 to 16, with an average of 6). Project Success in Boolean.  30% of projects are successful. Project # is sequential by company.

```
Company Name  Project #  Trait_1   Trait_2  Trait_3  Trait_4   Project Success
ABC              1         0          2        3       1           False
ABC              2         1          2        1       4           True
...
XYZ              1         2          4        2       1           True
```

I want to create a model which predicts Project Success, based on the traits (and maybe the company name).  What is the correct way to model this?  Should I treat the company name as an independent variable, and directly model the data as shown? (Different companies will probably have different success rates.) Should I apply some methodology to group an individual company's data into one row - and if so, what methodology?

I think logistic regression is a good choice here, I'm just not sure how and whether I should group the individual companies.

Comment: 22 hours. Anyone? I'll check back again tomorrow.

Comment: What do you mean by "group an individual company's data into one row"? Things you can do are (if relevant to the problem) keeping Company as a categorical variable (then you can decide how to encode it depending on the algorithm you will use) and keeping the project number, if you think that later projects might have a chance at being more successful

Comment: @DavideND - That's the reason I asked about a methodology, as I don't readily see a way to do it.  It wouldn't make sense to average the values of each column, and give a ratio of TRUEs/FALSEs.  With other type of data, this would make sense.  I may remove that sentence if it's throwing people off. (Re: "What do you mean by "group an individual company's data into one row"? )

Comment: yes, there is no reason to group by company. In that case you would end up with success ratios (?) and would need to do a regression between 0-1 instead of a classification, and it would honestly make less sense. I'll put up a longer answer to the question later :)